# NEXT page router deploy to Azure

Tags: reactjs, azure, next.js, app-router

I have a NEXT project to upload to Azure Web App, but let's get to the tests/cases.

1.: I ran the NEXT (App Router) build and uploaded the build files, without success, giving the 404 error or missing file in the Root. I uploaded this Build through FileZila and also through the VS Code Azure extension, but in both ways, the error was the same.

2.: I ran the NEXT (Page Router) build and also uploaded the build files following the same behavior as in description 1, but with the same result.

3.: I ran the build of a project with React Puro (react app) and got the Build files, uploaded it and it worked.

However, for NEXT I followed the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hZ_8TARnSQI and even though I followed exactly what the guy does in the video, I was not successful.

What catches the most attention is that the guy uploads a clean installation of NEXT with Page Router and I also tried that, but without success, at no point did I see him uploading the build.

The question is, has anyone been through the same thing or has experience uploading things to Azure Web App?

Thanks guys, good weekend to everyone.

I ran the build of a project with React Puro (react app) and got the Build files, uploaded it and it worked.

Comment: Hi, can you provide the code which you tried.

Comment: Hello !!! 

Here's my code and the files on Azure Web APP !!! 

VS Code Files -> https://imgur.com/dWWfzId
Azure -> https://imgur.com/gkR5SxV
Azure Folders -> https://imgur.com/dCSSdyk

This project have a NEXT Page Router clean installation.

Answer (score 0):

> The question is, has anyone been through the same thing or has experience uploading things to Azure Web App?

***I have reproduced the above requirement. Follow the below steps.***

- Open your terminal or command prompt and Navigate to the directory where you want to create your Next.js project.

```
npx create-next-app my-nextjs-app

(Or)

yarn create next-app my-nextjs-app
```

[image]

Now, here we can see the NEXT js project created. Then you can configure the routing as per your requirement.

***Run cmd:***

```
npm run dev

(or)

yarn dev
```

[image]

Then, we can deploy directly using Azure core tools extension installation in VS code editor.

[image]

- Login with the azure credentials and go to the App service create a new webapp with `node` Runtime & click on create.

[image]

`Nextappsample` is webapp which I created in the azure portal to deploy my `my-nextjs-app` from local.

**Deployment status:**
[image]

**Nextjs app:**
[image]